# What is "no-string-literal" rule in tslint?

Tags: typescript, tslint

The description found [here](http://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-string-literal) is very short:

> Disallows object access via string literals.

Is there any further documentation or example?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It means you can't access objects using the bracket notation. For example:

```
object["property"]
```

This way, a simple typo will throw an error and that's why it should be avoided. Instead, it is encouraged to use strongly-typed access.

Comment: Why do I need such of rule?

Comment: agreed, I dislike this rule becose sometimes you have to use object literals

Comment: The reason for this rule is because there is no need to use a string literal to access a property, other than cases like `obj["prop-erty"]` (which are allowed by this rule).

Comment: I do like this rule because it prevents accessing a private or protected property / method when we are not supposed to.  I do have to disable this rule on occasion (mostly on unit tests) inside the file itself.